# Missleading Python Error Message

Tags: python, syntax-error, cpython

If I have a **file** `python_error_msg.py`

```
x = [e for e in range(x)
x+=1
```

And I **run** it

```
$ python3 python_error_msg.py
```

The missing bracket gives the following error:

```
  File "python_error_msg.py", line 2
    x+=1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does it happen this way?  My error was in forgetting the `]` on the list comprehension.  Is this something that could be made better, or is it a deeper matter of how Python syntax works?

Also, where can I look in the 
 [codebase](https://github.com/python/cpython)
to get an idea of how error reporting works in Python?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the error isn't **official** until that second line. Python keeps reading while inside parentheses (or brackets, braces, etc)

What if your code were this?

```
x = [e for e in range(x)
]
```

No error.

That said, in these cases I wish `SyntaxError` would say:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax on line 2 of parenthetical
```

(After all, even the most experienced programmers forget to close parentheses sometimes

Comment: Exactly!  And I always end up reading line 2 very carefully, for a long time, until I figure it out.

Comment: At least 90% of `SyntaxError` questions on Stack Overflow are really the line above the error. At this point I just look there first.

Comment: I will probably get used to it.  I'm still really interested in how errors get reported.